# Dataframe aggregate method passing list problem

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

This maybe a bug, but what is your take on this pandas functionality:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'AB'])

def f(x):
    print(type(x))

df.agg(f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
A    None
B    None
dtype: object
```

However, if I wrap function call in the agg method in brackets passing a single function as a list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'AB'])

def f(x):
    print(type(x))


df.agg([f])
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
      A     B
      f     f
0  None  None
1  None  None
2  None  None
3  None  None
4  None  None
5  None  None
6  None  None
7  None  None
8  None  None
9  None  None
```

All that changed was passing the custom function as a single value list.

Comment: Nice catch even different behavior when you do with df.agg('sum') and df.agg(['sum'])

Comment: I did create a bug report on this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25454

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should consider using `apply` rather than `agg` as your function doesn't perform an aggragation of multiple values.