# Pandas - DataFrame aggregate behaving oddly

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, aggregate, series

Related to [Dataframe aggregate method passing list problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892437/dataframe-aggregate-method-passing-list-problem) and [Pandas fails to aggregate with a list of aggregation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890646/pandas-fails-to-aggregate-with-a-list-of-aggregation-functions)

Consider this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10))
df['a'] = [ 3 * x for x in range(10) ]
df['b'] = [ 1 -2 * x for x in range(10) ]
```

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) for `aggregate` you should be able to specify which columns to aggregate using a `dict` like this:

```
df.agg({'a' : 'mean'})
```

Which returns

```
a    13.5
```

But if you try to `aggregate` with a user-defined function like this one

```
def nok_mean(x):
    return np.mean(x)

df.agg({'a' : nok_mean})
```

It returns the mean for each row rather than the column

```
      a
0   0.0
1   3.0
2   6.0
3   9.0
4  12.0
5  15.0
6  18.0
7  21.0
8  24.0
9  27.0
```

Why does the user-defined function not return the same as aggregating with `np.mean` or `'mean'`?

This is using `pandas` version `0.23.4`, `numpy` version `1.15.4`, `python` version `3.7.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has to do with applying `np.mean` to a series. Let's look at a few examples:

```
def nok_mean(x):
    return x.mean()

df.agg({'a': nok_mean})

a    13.5
dtype: float64
```

this works as expected because you are using pandas version of mean, which can be applied to a series or a dataframe:

```
df['a'].agg(nok_mean)
df.apply(nok_mean)
```

Let's see what happens when `np.mean` is applied to a series:

```
def nok_mean1(x):
    return np.mean(x)

df['a'].agg(nok_mean1)
df.agg({'a':nok_mean1})
df['a'].apply(nok_mean1)
df['a'].apply(np.mean)
```

all return

```
0     0.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3     9.0
4    12.0
5    15.0
6    18.0
7    21.0
8    24.0
9    27.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

when you apply `np.mean` to a dataframe it works as expected:

```
df.agg(nok_mean1)
df.apply(nok_mean1)

a    13.5
b    -8.0
dtype: float64
```

in order to get `np.mean` to work as expected with a function pass an ndarray for x:

```
def nok_mean2(x):
    return np.mean(x.values)

df.agg({'a':nok_mean2})

a    13.5
dtype: float64
```

I am guessing all of this has to do with `apply`, which is why `df['a'].apply(nok_mean2)` returns an attribute error.

I am guessing [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L6287-L6289) in the source code

Answer (score 0):

When you define your `nok_mean` function, your function definition is basically saying that you want `np.mean` for each **row**

It finds the mean for each row and returns you the result.
For example, if your dataframe looked like this:

```
    a           b
0   [0, 0]      1
1   [3, 4]      -1
2   [6, 8]      -3
3   [9, 12]     -5
4   [12, 16]    -7
5   [15, 20]    -9
6   [18, 24]    -11
7   [21, 28]    -13
8   [24, 32]    -15
9   [27, 36]    -17
```

Then `df.agg({'a', nok_mean})` would return this:

```
    a
0   0.0
1   3.5
2   7.0
3   10.5
4   14.0
5   17.5
6   21.0
7   24.5
8   28.0
9   31.5
```

Comment: Thanks. How is `np.mean` being applied to the series rather than the rows?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how calculations are made on pandas side.

When you pass a dict of functions, the input is treated as a DataFrame instead of a flattened array. After that all calculations are made over the index axis by default. That's why you're getting the means by row.

If you go to the [docs page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) you'll see:

> The aggregation operations are always performed over an axis, either the
>   index (default) or the column axis. This behavior is different from
>   `numpy` aggregation functions (`mean`, `median`, `prod`, `sum`, `std`,
>   `var`), where the default is to compute the aggregation of the flattened
>   array, e.g., `numpy.mean(arr_2d)` as opposed to `numpy.mean(arr_2d,
>   axis=0)`.

__

I think the only way to emulate numpy's behavior and pass a dict of functions to agg at the same time is `df.agg(nok_mean)['a']`.

Comment: In the case of `df.agg({'a': np.mean})`, we're also passing a dict of functions, yet there pandas behaves as expected, so there's more to it than that. Similarly, note that `df.agg({'a': sum})` and `df.agg({'a': lambda x: sum(x)}` both produce the expected result, even though they follow the same pattern.